# Interstitial adsorbates

Tags: surfaces, adsorption

I have a poscar that I would like to place oxygen atoms as adsorbates in the subsurface. I have tried with Shaun's acat code but appears is not working for me. The posccar is shown below.

```
Co Cr Fe Ni                             
   1.00000000000000     
    10.0453568374981206    0.0000000000000000    0.0550632930546681
     5.0062629241308159    8.6637900144891251   -0.0307447571247709
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   24.5023355004677370
   Co   Cr   Fe   Ni
    24    24    24    24
Selective dynamics
Direct
  0.7484317155209226  0.2513638356015306  0.1254815499620392   F   F   F
  0.1672130297685186  0.9185659998157476  0.0423655957612539   F   F   F
  0.0024128917846937  0.0006368693967431  0.1251177360037659   F   F   F
  0.2472404547354330  0.7516658457698711  0.1253174855948984   F   F   F
  0.4986791697954516  0.7497224974724048  0.1245421004755940   F   F   F
  0.4183102184453631  0.9175024725961123  0.0427306917694636   F   F   F
  0.5005233982563055  0.5028030766782763  0.1263255330535529   F   F   F
  0.6637932465713661  0.6648289340226086  0.0411694970457788   F   F   F
  0.4148051600809368  0.9178461495668075  0.2924207711882258   T   T   T
  0.8338796964351900  0.5852326664824119  0.2090322624279182   F   F   F
  0.6683905896051491  0.6665521531107157  0.2919494222524963   T   T   T
  0.9137322442258432  0.4184043298653013  0.2918218756892721   T   T   T
  0.1659101027875440  0.4156907554642985  0.2915074418707615   T   T   T
  0.0849768851120345  0.5841691392627766  0.2093973584361279   F   F   F
  0.1646524639893301  0.1704140811992133  0.2931265725935911   T   T   T
  0.3304599132380304  0.3314956006892800  0.2078361637124431   F   F   F
  0.0812960413834357  0.5880794902365066  0.4555792089417541   T   T   T
  0.4994197558394441  0.2490587492264744  0.3760560267155630   T   T   T
  0.3333921183195137  0.3420136469527384  0.4560217103069046   T   T   T
  0.5826752923091105  0.0857557180115605  0.4562264905890454   T   T   T
  0.8361011910506737  0.0816930595460893  0.4557185355279263   T   T   T
  0.7530492451163983  0.2473081031331254  0.3756764049814374   T   T   T
  0.8301401794437534  0.8392046371404343  0.4575945680681187   T   T   T
  0.9990613308381326  0.9979081941329535  0.3755447194682439   T   T   T
  0.9971429636928946  0.2522458351632153  0.1243171831461751   F   F   F
  0.9173969055062088  0.9243213954712743  0.0415462838229530   F   F   F
  0.2532328618483248  0.9912372851549591  0.1247613899134663   F   F   F
  0.9158846146946971  0.6649375277963188  0.0403872990614644   F   F   F
  0.0024110322067799  0.7449034237646117  0.1251928215763556   F   F   F
  0.1668800967370530  0.1660149380313101  0.0391693010992924   F   F   F
  0.4145209940205419  0.1686122327575248  0.0423935979957335   F   F   F
  0.0019224850701747  0.5002131357099415  0.1274453925201016   F   F   F
  0.6643301274840190  0.9192298301080949  0.2909060284359840   T   T   T
  0.5840635721728802  0.5909880621379457  0.2082129504896244   F   F   F
  0.9197107341637500  0.6574724555144138  0.2915108972239469   T   T   T
  0.5825512813613685  0.3316041944629831  0.2070539657281358   F   F   F
  0.6707997987754361  0.4102323661913387  0.2904763634920180   T   T   T
  0.8335467634037173  0.8326816046979744  0.2058359677659638   F   F   F
  0.0811876606872062  0.8352788994241891  0.2090602646624049   F   F   F
  0.6666631390832718  0.1697828750236400  0.2935790889719558   T   T   T
  0.3287222623539052  0.5949995619541201  0.4566661274696794   T   T   T
  0.2507297661860802  0.2452335156972610  0.3782780233787296   T   T   T
  0.5900673674316123  0.3266313292879156  0.4552826212887701   T   T   T
  0.2489382055833093  0.0011177879441811  0.3741236488020183   T   T   T
  0.3333049617800694  0.0954306189689573  0.4617211593524514   T   T   T
  0.5069854991928138  0.4944701746721915  0.3719734131547170   T   T   T
  0.7463376705174738  0.5022245251682501  0.3772195083157827   T   T   T
  0.3321672019729938  0.8487864324747707  0.4579998120019802   T   T   T
  0.9162766261883135  0.1670506690443787  0.0417170310293500   F   F   F
  0.9156348408059642  0.4208833853925711  0.0416680593854295   F   F   F
  0.6638573836196215  0.4167482971811012  0.0427373586771225   F   F   F
  0.1644966505612686  0.6696213567857683  0.0421395064179180   F   F   F
  0.4141908497179116  0.6702206541091940  0.0436478982229787   F   F   F
  0.2505031653515672  0.2514744230863357  0.1253016876192419   F   F   F
  0.6671950880963564  0.9146088546634559  0.0412477173410366   F   F   F
  0.5011301297450359  0.0015898949770516  0.1254391147214591   F   F   F
  0.5829432928549849  0.8337173357110430  0.2083836976960143   F   F   F
  0.5823015074726285  0.0875500520592425  0.2083347260521009   F   F   F
  0.3305240502862929  0.0834149638477655  0.2094040253437868   F   F   F
  0.8311633172279329  0.3362880234524397  0.2088061730845894   F   F   F
  0.0808575163845759  0.3368873207758583  0.2103145648896501   F   F   F
  0.9178620539490372  0.9181632848813880  0.2921614142707068   T   T   T
  0.3338617547630278  0.5812755213301273  0.2079143840077009   F   F   F
  0.1667427441640129  0.6691629774099748  0.2916689190446753   T   T   T
  0.2501005544956555  0.4971190651557775  0.3752504245138626   T   T   T
  0.2465450490318301  0.7513602656366625  0.3737836365295550   T   T   T
  0.9959441676473952  0.7502164470050144  0.3761722958557462   T   T   T
  0.5006832374805985 -0.0046823132578043  0.3771502923241621   T   T   T
  0.7479199814638383  0.0015639501390249  0.3769771482198781   T   T   T
  0.5907294015449800  0.5811057710859650  0.4593840788246640   T   T   T
 -0.0060356496498379  0.2509365579997814  0.3746997440371634   T   T   T
  0.8337131135973636  0.3384461954663572  0.4589575960453217   T   T   T
  0.7491453254479623  0.4999420685284264  0.1253274286111932   F   F   F
  0.7525172797094726  0.9990417994750018  0.1245053594957000   F   F   F
  0.1659916469114435  0.4166267850617231  0.0419841126835294   F   F   F
  0.4164851590236438  0.4195902143823460  0.0412357760750623   F   F   F
  0.7488913776000459  0.7483211782917962  0.1243236794642684   F   F   F
  0.6650578055559109  0.1674124030264323  0.0415158212312434   F   F   F
  0.4996344114965225  0.2515395125269748  0.1247577710853136   F   F   F
  0.2510709289178692  0.4996037034576872  0.1251508454354209   F   F   F
  0.4151278078261990  0.1660138252756776  0.2929391613717844   T   T   T
  0.4191068649976099  0.6656963488165302  0.2910043222214981   T   T   T
  0.8326583135781078  0.0832934517283874  0.2086507793501937   F   F   F
  0.0831518256903081  0.0862568810490103  0.2079024427417338   F   F   F
  0.4141780161790669  0.4152819982214173  0.2911292247327950   T   T   T
  0.3317244722225823  0.8340790696931037  0.2081824878979148   F   F   F
  0.1672808087447653  0.9188007288622816  0.2911744749016252   T   T   T
  0.9184911724707188  0.1647217763839646  0.2912823563402203   T   T   T
  0.0786746230769518  0.8394704018569830  0.4571878949908471   T   T   T
  0.0812918002957800  0.3388228622899257  0.4577279953776053   T   T   T
  0.4995222746832525  0.7476613523226699  0.3754402597886074   T   T   T
  0.7504604731685881  0.7509375893853185  0.3748486140777815   T   T   T
  0.0779944725298367  0.0905558955121346  0.4570840112996290   T   T   T
  0.0010021949552336  0.4974678493264066  0.3749986037544817   T   T   T
  0.8340126184872778  0.5881395290292224  0.4574595912618843   T   T   T
  0.5875529134078941  0.8320089079782008  0.4577610944684899   T   T   T
```

Comment: You cannot ping people who have not yet interacted with the question. Also, please do not make new tags.

Comment: It’s not clear what complications do you have: with placing oxygen atoms or computer simulation?

Comment: I will post an answer soon

Comment: @ShaunHan That will be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow identifying subsurface interstitial sites (a.k.a. "6fold" sites in ACAT), you need to set `allow_6fold=True` when identifying adsorption sites.  For your alloy surface, you can print all "6fold" sites by

```
from ase.io import read
from ase.visualize import view
from acat.adsorption_sites import SlabAdsorptionSites

atoms = read('POSCAR')
sas = SlabAdsorptionSites(atoms, surface='fcc111',
                          allow_6fold=True)
all_sites = sas.get_sites()
for st in all_sites:
    if st['site'] == '6fold':
        print(st)
```

You will get information of the subsurface interstitial sites in dictionaries like the following

```
{'site': '6fold', 'surface': 'fcc111', 'morphology': 'subsurf', 
 'position': array([10.0712727 ,  1.49667529, 10.24772459]), 
 'normal': array([-0.01811144, -0.0217874 ,  0.99959856]), 
 'indices': (20, 21, 23, 70, 71, 92), 'composition': None, 
 'subsurf_index': None, 'subsurf_element': None, 'label': None}

{'site': '6fold', 'surface': 'fcc111', 'morphology': 'subsurf', 
 'position': array([13.79910872,  7.94552728, 10.21427464]), 
 'normal': array([-0.00150985,  0.02617928,  0.99965612]), 
 'indices': (20, 22, 23, 66, 68, 88), 'composition': None, 
 'subsurf_index': None, 'subsurf_element': None, 'label': None}
```

For example, if you want to insert interstitial oxygen at the site that coordinates the 6 atoms with indices `(20, 22, 23, 66, 68, 88)`, you can just do

```
from acat.build import add_adsorbate

add_adsorbate(atoms, adsorbate='O', all_sites=all_sites,
              indices=(20, 21, 23, 70, 71, 92))
view(atoms)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Solved

Comment: After optimization the oxygen moves up to the first surface. Will I be correct to restrain the movement in the C direction so I can get a diffusion distance?

Comment: @NanaKofiBoakye I think oxygen are too big to be in the interstial site of a metal surface. It's no surprise coming to the surface

Comment: So is it correct to fix the C so that the atom cannot move up during optimization?